# What Tor-friendly hosting providers allow anonymous accounts?

Tags: relays, anonymity, exit-relays

There are at least three levels to "Tor-friendly":

1. allow clients;
2. allow non-exit relays;
3. allow exit relays.

In any case, the provider must accept SSH connections via Tor.

By "anonymous accounts", I mean:

1. no contact information except email required (or none checked, if "required");
2. payment accepted in Bitcoins, or by cash through the mail.

Comment: A hosting provider should not normally know you're hosting a hidden service. Hidden service uses Tor in client mode. There should be no public information that you're the one who hosts this service. Furthermore, provider should not spy on your disk, your RAM or your network traffic. So every decent provider should be a candidate for option number 2.

Comment: How do customers assess providers' decency? From a security perspective, it's always prudent to assume the worst. For non-exit relays, all traffic is encrypted, so it doesn't matter. For exit relays, there may be unencrypted traffic, but there's nothing that must be kept private. Hidden services are much more problematic, however, so I'll make that a separate question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Tor community maintains a list of ISPs that have worked for others in the past along with some comments of people's experiencs working with each service. That list is here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/GoodBadISPs

The Bitcoin wiki maintains a list of VPS providers that accept payment in Bticoin. This does not mean that they are necessarily anonymous. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Virtual_private_server

Comment: OK, I'll look through them and see which ones are OK with anonymous accounts. If I were to run an exit, for example, I wouldn't want to depend on promises from the provider ;)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest provider of free, tor-friendly anonymous was Freedom Hosting, but it has been closed by police so you have to look for alternatives.

My results of googling, which may be relevant for you :

- http://www.hacker10.com/tag/anonymous-webhosting/
- http://www.privacy-toolz.com/anonymous-web-hosting.htm
- https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Hidden_Services